# Nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException:Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jdbc, datasource

We have legacy software that was running properly for the last 6-7 years. Recently we started getting the below error:

```
Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

[image: Error Log]

We only see this error when the EC2 CPU utilization goes high(Approx above 80%). The backend is developed in spring boot. However, we use DriverManagerDataSource for DB connection and do not use any connection pooling.

```
@Bean(name = "datasource")
@Primary
public DriverManagerDataSource getDataSourceFactory() {
DriverManagerDataSource database = new DriverManagerDataSource();
database.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
database.setUsername(System.getenv("USER"));
database.setPassword(System.getenv("PASSWORD"));
database.setUrl(System.getenv("URL"));
return database;
}
```

MySql version is 5.7 and DB wait_timeout and interactive_timeout are 60 minutes. Can someone help me to find out what's the possible issue and the solution for this?
Also, does the JDBC connector has any limit on how many max connections it can create at any given time?

Comment: are the db connections being closed properly after use? are you using spring repository methods to query the database? do the db operations take a lot of time to finish? What is the setting on mysql side for the maximum number of connections it can accept? Do you have too many connections open that what is configured at mysql level?

Comment: We use spring repository methods, so the db connections are being closed properly. 
We have a 10000 max number of connections on the DB side.

Comment: Did you try `wait_timeout` and `autoReconnect=true` ?

Comment: @Mehmet Güngören yes